xpath plugin alternative in cypress for "locator or selector" in angular applications
As the xpath plugin is deprecated in cypress. It is becoming difficult to find the locator without xpath in angular based web applications. Has anyone found some alternative to xpath plugin on locating the elements in angular application?!
Alternative to deprecated xpath plugin to locate the dynamically changing DOM elements.

Can you add a sample HTML? Cypress prefers using more traditional CSS Selectors, which Angular applications should definitely have. Also, while the plugin is deprecated, you may still be able to use it (at your own risk - Cypress won't be updating the package anymore)

When you say It is becoming difficult to find the locator without xpath in angular based web applications, this is incorrect. Cypress does not care if you are using Angular or another framework, it just reads the DOM. For example, the button selector would be cy.get('button#123').

@UChin is correct in using document.evaluate(), but the results you get back are an object containing one or more nodes.
These must be parsed to get the elements, then wrapped with cy.wrap() to be able to use them with other Cypress commands such as .should() or .click().
If I create a small page with a button like this:
<body>
  <button id="123" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <p id="result"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
  </script>
</body>

I can use the xpath custom command like this:
Cypress.Commands.add('xpath', (xpathSelector) => {
  return cy.document({log: false}).then(document => {
    const nodes = document.evaluate(xpathSelector, document)
    return cy.wrap(nodes.iterateNext())
  })
})

cy.xpath('//button[@id="123"]').click()

cy.xpath('//p[@id="result"]').should('have.text', 'Hello World')



What about selecting multiple elements?
This requires some code to extract all the found elements
Cypress.Commands.add('xpath', (xpathSelector) => {
  return cy.document({log:false}).then(document => {
    const nodes = document.evaluate(xpathSelector, document)
    let results = [], node;
    while((node = nodes.iterateNext()) !== null) {
      results.push(Cypress.$(node))
    }
    return cy.wrap(Cypress.$.fn.add.call(...results))
  })
})

If I add a <ul> with <li> to the html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>

I can test it like this
cy.xpath('//li')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .each(($li, index) => {
    const expected = ['one', 'two']
    expect($li.text()).to.eq(expected[index])
  })



Note - don't use xpath, it is no longer required. This code is just for demo purposes.

Modern browsers have xpath built in, so you can add a custom command to xpath use in a query
Cypress.Commands.add('xpath', (xpathSelector) => {
  return cy.document().then(document => {
    return document.evaluate(xpathSelector, document)
  })
}

cy.xpath('my-xpath-selector')
  .should(...)


for me it did not work when added the custom command in e2e.js In cypress when given cy.xpath('//button[@id=""]`).click or some action,  cypress throws error on "an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object."
